# I have a probabilty issue with random.choices

Tags: python, random, probability

Hey so i made an program to choose a random number betwen 1.01 and 999.99 with probabilty (1/2 * 0.98 for 2 1/3*0.98 for 3 ect) but i dont know why its seem to do around 1/10 for 2 and 15/85 for 3 anyone know why its does that an how to fix it?

````
proba = []
nombre = []
for numéroNombre in range (100,100000,1):
    proba1 = ((1000000/numéroNombre)/10000) * 0.98
    proba.append(proba1)
    nombre.append(numéroNombre/100)
b = 0
c = 0
b = 0
a = [0]
for i in range(0,100):
    b = a[0]
    a = random.choices(nombre,weights=proba)
    if int(a[0]) < int(b):
        b = b + 1
    else:
        c = c +1
print(nombre[99],proba[99])
print("2 ou moins : " + str(b))
print("plus que 2 : " + str(c))```
````

Comment: Do your probability values actually add up to 1? How did you decide on the `0.98` constant? Also, did you try checking the actual values that end up in `proba`? Like, all of them, not just `proba[99]`?

Comment: i tryed some of them to verify and 0.98 is code of its will be" gambling " (not real money ) based so i did a rtp of 0.98

Comment: but i tested the proba before and they are pretty accurate

Comment: The numbers are picked with frequency proportionate to the weights. Scaling everything by 0.98 doesn't make a difference because it has to pick *something* each time, and you're *uniformly* scaling the *relative* probabilities. At any rate, if you have weights like `[1/2, 1/3, 1/4...]` then the probability of picking the first value will be the relative weight *divided by the sum of all the weights* (which is to say, the values are *normalized*). This has to happen because, again, each random selection has to choose *one of* the values.

Comment: Anyway, part of why you get strange results is that as you try to count the results of the `random.choices`, you *re-do the selection each time through the loop*.